# Type value into email input field with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write an email address into an input field with JavaScript. It should not be that hard. But I'm not able to do it. The input field has validation. Maybe this is the problem.

I already tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sc-kEYyzF mqvXI')[0].setAttribute("value", "xyz@gmail.com");
document.getElementById("email").value = "xyz00@gmail.com";
```

But after I click on the submit button, the input disappears. I'm trying this on this website: https://welcome.onelog.ch/

EDIT: Thanks to @epascarello. With his code I found the correct solution

**SOLUTION:**

````
let lastValue = input.value;
input.value = 'xyz@gmail.com';
let event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
event.simulated = true;
let tracker = input._valueTracker;
if (tracker) {
  tracker.setValue(lastValue);
}
input.dispatchEvent(event);```
````

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Seblor doubt they can recreate that site to make it happen in a fiddle....

Comment: @epascarello No need to recreate the whole website. At least include the relevant HTML, since I don't think many people will go on some random website to reverse engineer it. But you've got a point that it would be complicated to include the validation process in a snippet.

Comment: I feel you are getting some console error, when i have look at your website. The class name i verified was `sc-kEYyzF cbCwbw` instead of  `sc-kEYyzF mqvXI`, which may be thrown an error as `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined`. It is an guess, you might have a look at your console.

Comment: @RinshanKolayil The code of the website is automatically generated every time you reload it.

Comment: The problem is with whatever framework the site is using. It does not recognize setting the value with JavaScript. So what you will have to do is figure out how to trick it to recognize you entered in a value. I am guessing it is Ember....

Comment: @ManuelBerger, Oh sorry my bad, you codes seems to be ok (i.e It will run without errors) but you need to have a look at console, and try to use `document.getElementsByClassName('sc-kEYyzF cbCwbw')[0].value = "xyz@gmail.com"`

Comment: To the people reading this.... react is not seeing the value change

Comment: @epascarello Ok this is why it doesn't accept my inputs with JavaScript. My skills aren't that good. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is it is React and react adds events and stuff which tracks the values. When you set the value directly it just ignores the change. It is no different when you set the value and the onchange event does not fire.

So you need to do some magic to get React to see the change.

```
const tb = document.getElementById("email");
tb._valueTracker && tb._valueTracker.setValue(tb.value);
tb.value = "foo@example.com";
tb.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true, simulated: true, }));
```

Comment: That looks a lot like magic. But should I define 'tracker' somewhere? If I run this code in chrome console it returns an error. Uncaught ReferenceError: tracker is not defined

Comment: fixed it so it is defined

Answer (score -1):

Form resets after submit. Try on your form to add onsubmit ="return false"